# Create PDF from HTML and save it automatically on DB - Logo Image is not displaying in PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jspdf

I am having a problem with an image that is not displaying when I save the generated PDF file and save it automatically in the DB. I have two functionalities. One, you click on the button and you download the generated pdf file which comes with a logo at the top; Second, once you approve a request, I save a PDF file in the DB, but the logo is not coming.
This is my code. Where when I create the PDF works fine, but when I upload the attachment does not display the image:

```
function createPDF(){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

  // var doc = new jsPDF();
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  pdf.setFont("helvetica");
  pdf.text("STAR PROGRAM", 238, 105);
  pdf.text('Staff Teamwork Appreciation and Recognition', 145, 125);
  pdf.setFontSize(20);
  pdf.fromHTML($('#PdfDiv').html(), 40, 155, {
    'width': 540,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
  });
  var image = data:image/jpeg;base64,theImageBase64CodeIsHereButIDeletedItToSaveSpace";
  pdf.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 230, 40, 160, 40);
  pdf.save('START_' + $scope.nominee + '.pdf');            
}
```

The code above works.
However when I use the same settings I used to set the pdf variable, however this time I create a BLOB to save the automatically a PDF, then the PDF is saved in the DB but there is no image. This is my code:

```
function uploadAttachment(name) {
        //here is the code above without the last line (pdf.save)
        var data = pdf.output(); 
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length); 
        var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var blob = new Blob([array], {
            type: 'image/pdf', encoding:'raw'
        });

        //var blob = new Blob([array], {
        //    type: 'application/pdf;base64'
        //});

        var reader = new FileReader();
        var getFileBuffer = function (blob) {

            var deferred = $.Deferred();


            reader.onload = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }

            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

            return deferred.promise();
        };

        getFileBuffer(blob).then(function (buffer) {
            timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
            var binary = "";
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var i = bytes.byteLength;
            while (i--) {
                binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
            }
            $http({                    
                method: "POST",
                url: endpointUrl + "(" + Id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='START_"+ name+"23.pdf')",
                data: binary,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-length": binary.byteLength
                }
            })
            .then(function (success) {
                alert("You have attached the file succesfully!");
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("File already exists! Try a different name.");
            });

        });
    }
```

Has anyone had this problem before? I can't find the reason why I am not able to save the PDF with the logo image. Please help me.

Comment: var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,verylongbase64;'
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180); maybe this somehow can help

Comment: Thank you Nikita, but I have done that :( I can see the image if I download it to my PC but I can't see it if I automatically save the PDF to my List.

Comment: Did you try using PNG instead of JPEG?

Comment: When I try to use PNG I get another error saying PNG is not supported.. I was trying with PNG before and that's why I changed to JPEG... But still I don't think that the type of image is what is not placing the image there.. I think there is something I need to do when creating the blob.. but haven't found anything related to my problem.

Comment: I still was not able to solve this problem, so I am generating pdfs without the logo when people click in my link.. has anyone found any workaround?